# GuidedActionEditText example snippet

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-7.1-nougat, leanback

I am developing a leanback app using `GuidedStepFragment`. I want to use `GuidedActionEditText` but don't know how and google has very low results about that.

Explicitly I want to add a `GuidedActionEditText` to a list of `GuidedAction`s but can not do that.

Thanks

Comment: did you find any example or snippet ?

Answer (score -1):

Hello Please find example for GuidedActionEditText.

```
public class NameEditFragment  extends GuidedStepSupportFragment {

    private static final String TAG = "NameEditFragment";
    private final int ACTION_NAME = 0;

       @Override
        public int onProvideTheme() {
                return R.style.Guidestyle;
         }

        private  void addEditableAction(List<GuidedAction> actions,long id, String       title, String desc,int inputType){
              actions.add(new GuidedAction.Builder(getActivity())
              .id(id)
              .editable(true)
              .title(title).inputType(inputType)
             .build());
       }
      @NonNull
     @Override
     public GuidanceStylist.Guidance onCreateGuidance(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      GuidanceStylist.Guidance guidance = new GuidanceStylist.Guidance("Edit your Alias “, "", "", null);
            return guidance;
     }

    @Override
     public void onCreateActions(@NonNull List<GuidedAction> actions, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              addEditableAction(actions,ACTION_NAME,"Name","", InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
      }
    @Override
      public long onGuidedActionEditedAndProceed(GuidedAction action) {
          if (action.getId() == ACTION_NAME) {
             }
          return super.onGuidedActionEditedAndProceed(action)
       }}
```

Guidestyle

```
<style name="GuidedActionItemTitleStyle">
<item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
<item name="android:alpha">@string/lb_guidedactions_item_unselected_text_alpha</item>
<item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
<item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-condensed</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/lb_guidedactions_item_unselected_text_color</item>
<item name="android:textSize">@dimen/lb_guidedactions_item_title_font_size</item>
<item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:maxLength">32</item>
<item name="android:textAlignment">viewStart</item>
```